# jax-rs response.getEntity not working

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I want to use javax.ws.rs.core.Response to send and receive an Card entity object. But I don't know how to convert the contents back in to a Card object.

My testCreate() method should execute the create(Card card) method, receive back the json and convert it in to a card object. But I somehow always get type mismatches or it says that the getEntity() method can't be executed like this: response.getEntity(Card.class).

Does anybody know how I have to handle the response correctly so that I can convert the returned json entity in to a Card object again?

Here my CardResource method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response create(Card card) {
    Card c = dao.create(card);
    if(c.equals(null)) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Create failed!").build();
    }

    return Response.status(Status.OK)
            .entity(c)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
}
```

And here my CardResourceTests class

```
@Test
public void testCreate() {
    boolean thrown = false;
    CardResource resource = new CardResource();

    Card c = new Card(1, "Cardname", "12345678", 1, 1, 
            "cardname.jpg", new Date(), new Date());        

    try {
        Response result = resource.create(c);
        System.out.println(result.getEntity(Card.class)); // not working!!!
        if(result.getStatus() != 200) {
            thrown = true;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        thrown = true;          
    }

    assertEquals("Result", false, thrown);
}
```

And here my Card.class

```
@XmlRootElement
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class Card {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private Integer id;

@Persistent
private String name;

@Persistent
private String code;

@Persistent 
private Integer cardProviderId; 

@Persistent 
private Integer codeTypeId;

@Persistent
private String picturePath;

@Persistent
private Boolean valid;

@Persistent 
private Date mobCreationDate;

@Persistent
private Date mobModificationDate;

@Persistent
private Date creationDate;  

@Persistent
private Date modificationDate;

public Card() {
    this.setId(null);
    this.setName(null);
    this.setCode(null);
    this.setCardProviderId(null);       
    this.setCodeTypeId(null);
    this.setPicturePath(null);
    this.setMobCreationDate(null);
    this.setMobModificationDate(null);
    this.setCreationDate(null);
    this.setModificationDate(null);
}

public Card(Integer id, String name, String code, Integer cardProviderId, 
    Integer codeTypeId, String picturePath,
    Date mobCreationDate, Date mobModificationDate) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setCode(code);
    this.setCardProviderId(cardProviderId);     
    this.setCodeTypeId(codeTypeId);
    this.setPicturePath(picturePath);
    this.setMobCreationDate(mobCreationDate);
    this.setMobModificationDate(mobModificationDate);
    this.setCreationDate(new Date());
    this.setModificationDate(new Date());
}

public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public Integer getCardProviderId() {
    return cardProviderId;
}

public void setCardProviderId(Integer cardProviderId) {
    this.cardProviderId = cardProviderId;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Integer getCodeTypeId() {
    return codeTypeId;
}

public void setCodeTypeId(Integer codeTypeId) {
    this.codeTypeId = codeTypeId;
}

public String getPicturePath() {
    return picturePath;
}

public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
    this.picturePath = picturePath;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public Date getModificationDate() {
    return modificationDate;
}

public void setModificationDate(Date modificationDate) {
    this.modificationDate = modificationDate;
}

public Date getMobCreationDate() {
    return mobCreationDate;
}

public void setMobCreationDate(Date mobCreationDate) {
    this.mobCreationDate = mobCreationDate;
}

public Date getMobModificationDate() {
    return mobModificationDate;
}

public void setMobModificationDate(Date mobModificationDate) {
    this.mobModificationDate = mobModificationDate;
}

public Boolean getValid() {
    return valid;
}

public void setValid(Boolean valid) {
    this.valid = valid;
}
}
```

And here my CardDAO class

```
public class CardDAO {
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CardDAO.class.getName()); 

public Card create(Card card) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    Card c = new Card(card.getId(), card.getName(), card.getCode(), 
        card.getCardProviderId(), card.getCodeTypeId(), card.getPicturePath(),
        new Date(), new Date());

    try {
        pm.makePersistent(c);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.severe("Create failed: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    return c;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test it just like a simple method or like a service?

Comment: I test it as simple method call not as service. No web container involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that it is correct to call the annotated web-service method just like a simple method with params. Try to remove all annotations from your `CardResource` class and invoke this method simply like a class method.

Comment: I have removed the annotations but it doesn't change anything. The error message is: "The method getEntity in type Response is not applicapible for the arguments (Class<Card>)" at following line of code: System.out.println(result.getEntity(Card.class));. getEntity seems to return an object and when I debug I see that the object is filled with the card items but I can't convert it in to a Card object. I rather think I'm using getEntity in a wrong way. But I can't figure out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: When I execute following command: System.out.println(result.getEntity()); then I get following output: com.acolsolutions.cardkeeper.server.entities.Card@20d9896e.

Comment: thanks all for your help so far. i appriciate it. I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: try adding `toString()` method to your `Card` class in order to print it correctly.

Comment: tried but it just prints out: com.acolsolutions.cardkeeper.server.entities.Card@172fb0af

Comment: try `result.getEntity(Card.class).toString()`

Comment: it's a funny thing that it doesn't seem to be supported to do unit tests with jax-rs methods directly. using a web container would be an integration test. but before i integration test i would like to unit test. but there are no examples. nobody seems to be doing it that way.... or testing is for the weak ones, real men don't test ;-)

Comment: well, it is not that difficult to run it on a web server. And though you will get a test result, which will be much closer to real situation then in then unit test case.

Comment: yea i guess you are right. seems to be best practice doing it this way. at least i can test the status with unit tests. this is working. and then for the content i'll use the integration tests with the web container started. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Card class using `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` annotations to enable **JAXB** mapping JSON to/from POJO?

See example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Book {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    String id;
//...
```

Comment: I just added my card class. could it be that all the attributes have to be annotated with the @XmlElement?

Comment: yes, the @XmlElement is used to help JAXB populating the class attributes.